# How to make the same Openstack Keystone authentication request in the V3 and V2 API?

Tags: openstack, keystone

I have a single machine installation of OpenStack Mitaka on a Fedora 24 server VM that includes Keystone and Swift. I went through the OpenStack installation instructions and got the v3 keystone API working but some other software I'm installing depends on v2. I am unable to authenticate with the v2 API and get a token, even though the equivalent request to the v3 API works correctly. Here are the two requests I'm making:

V3:

```
curl -i   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '
{ "auth": {
    "identity": {
      "methods": ["password"],
      "password": {
        "user": {
          "name": "admin",
          "domain": { "name": "default" },
          "password": "PASSWORD"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'   http://SERVER:35357/v3/auth/tokens
```

V2:

```
curl -d -H "Content-Type: application/json"
'{"auth": {
      "passwordCredentials": {
             "username": "admin",
             "password": "PASSWORD"
      },
      "tenantName": "admin"
    }
   }'  http://SERVER:35357/v2.0/tokens
```

The V3 request returns a token, but the V2 request fails with:

```
{"error": {"message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", "code": 401, "title": "Unauthorized"}}
```

Are these API requests equivalent? Are there keystone.conf settings that need to be changed in order to make the V2 API work?

Answer (score 0):

If you run v2 keystone version by default it starts up on http://SERVER:5000/v2.0 make sure your port is open and v2 version is enabled and working.

Comment: The v2 API is definitely up and running and I have tried the request both on 5000 and 35357. If I change the format of the body of the request and misspell passwordCredentials it complains specifically about that element being missing, and that's only part of the v2 API AFAIK.